# Importing mathcal from a font alongside another

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math, math-fonts

I would like to import the mathcal font from *DejaVu Math TeX Gyre* without overwriting the  mathcal font of my global math font. I assumed I could just do:

```
\newfontfamily\djmathfont{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}
\newcommand{\mathcalbis}[1]{{\djmathfont \mathcal{#1}}}
```

But it does not work (it just produces the mathcal of my global math font).

Note that I **don't** want to do something along the lines of:

```
\setmathfont{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}[range=\mathcal]
```

**Edit.** Here is how I would define my custom `\mathsf` without overriding the default one:

```
\newfontfamily\custommathsffont{Lato Regular}[Scale=MatchLowercase,NFSSFamily=custommathsf]
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbis}{\encodingdefault}{custommathsf}{m}{n}
```

This is easy because `\mathsfbis` is then directly the font `Lato Regular`. In the case of `\mathcalbis`, I have to somehow select the subset of calligraphic letters in the font `DejaVu Math Tex Gyre`, and I don't know how to adapt this method.

Answer (score 1):

If you need two different calligraphic fonts, you can set one as `\mathcal` and the other as `\mathscr`, leaving the original `\mathcal` unchanged, with

```
\setmathfont{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}[range={scr, bfscr}, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

If this does not cover your use case, seriously consider whether you really, truly need three different script variants of the same letter in the same paper.  If what you actually want is a calligraphic alphabet, a script alphabet, and a few individual letters from another font you like better, `range=` can replace only that one letter. Or maybe you want one of the other math alphabets that’s more distinct, such as Fraktur.

Otherwise, you’d want to do something like

```
\setmathfontface\mathcalbis{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newcommand\mcalbisD{\mathcalbis{}}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion will allow me to use `\mathscr` from the font, not `\mathcal` right? Your last suggestion I'm aware of, but it only allows to define `\mathcalbis` one letter at a time, not ideal.

Comment: @Pece In Unicode, `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` are the same alphabet. Unless you set one or the other to a different font (or stylistic set, or alternate) with `range=`, they will be identical. This code will allow you to use the font’s script/calligraphic alphabet as `\mathscr`.